# Powershell: recursively dumping all non-directory child items in a folder into a specific path

Tags: file, powershell, filesystems

I'm trying to automate a simple desktop clearing program, and I tried writing a command to revert everything my program does. Currently, my program sorts everything on my desktop into a folder called "media" (which is on the desktop), which contains further subdirectories for each category of item. Essentially,

`Desktop >> Media >> {bunch of dirs for item categories}`

So I'm trying to write a command that takes all the sorted items from the subdirectories and dumps them back into the desktop without moving the folders themselves. So far I've tried:

`dir -attributes !directory -recurse | foreach-object {move-item $_ -destination "$home/desktop"}`

This creates the problem of powershell trying to move an object whose ACTUAL path is something like:

`C:\________\desktop\media\images\sample.jpg`

using this path:

`C:\________\desktop\media\sample.jpg`

because I'm executing the command from the "media" folder, resulting in errors like this:

`move-item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\bhiggins\desktop\media\Basic Engineering Circuit Analy - J. David
Irwin.pdf' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:55
+ ... -recurse | foreach-object {move-item $_ -destination "$home/desktop"}
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\bhiggi...David Irwin.pdf:String) [Move-Item], ItemNotFou
   ndException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand`

So how would I modify my command such that the correct path is passed to the move-item instruction while maintaining the execution location to be "media"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that I understood your problem here.
You really don't need **foreach-Object** to do this.
This will take whatever is in the source folder and move it to destination folder (in your case Desktop)

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -recurse | Move-Item -Destination $destination
```